# How to set data-bound ComboBox selected value to nothing or default?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, null

A `ComboBox` is bound to a `BindingList<T>` instance as a data source, the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties are set and working as supposed.

At some point of the code I am to switch the selected value programmatically given a `ValueMember` value and this works perfectly in a perfect case done simple as just `comboBox.SelectedValue = newValue`. But in other cases `newValue` supplied can easily be null (or just something that doesn't occur among the actual keys in the data source perhaps) and these situations are to be handled silently and, at the same time, as reasonably as possible - the selection is to be either reset to the "nothing selected" state or to some default (like a pre-configured value or the first in the list maybe). But what to do if the default value doesn't occur in the data source either or if the data source is just empty? The `ComboBox.SelectedValue` property does not support setting it null. Just ignoring the problem leaving the previous selection remain unchanged as some people suggest is not an option because the fact this part of the code is reached can often mean the whole situation has changed, the previous options set and the previous choice can happen to have no or different meaning in the new context.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted an answer for a very similar question about the SelectedIndex property:

[How to deleselect / blank a databound ComboBox? SelectedIndex = -1 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427172/how-to-deleselect-blank-a-databound-combobox-selectedindex-1-does-not-work)

The workaround I posted there, namely setting FormattingEnabled = true, works just as well when setting SelectedItem = null.

Obviously, this doesn't change the fact that this is still an unsupported operation, so if you're concerned about "staying within the lines", this won't help.  But it does seem to make it work in the cases that I've tried, and since it adds zero complexity to my code, I found it to be a very acceptable workaround for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `trycatch` so when ever your value is `null` or does not exists it will throw an exception so when exception is thrown it will go to the `catch` block

```
try
   {
      ComboBox.SelectedValue = null; //this will throw exception
      ComboBox.SelectedValue = "text that dont exists" //this will throw exception

   }

catch (Exception exception)
   {
      ComboBox.SelectedValue = "0";
   }
```

so in `catch` whenever an `exception` is thrown you can set its value to  `"0"` for selecting `empty`

Comment: First of all the "1" value will rarely occur in the source data actually, GUIDs will be used most often though support for other kinds of keys is to be implemented too (non-numeric strings will be used in some cases, numbers support can happen to be needed in future) so chances are "1" is not going to be present in the source BindingList (and  the ComboBox itself, especially as it is bound to it, or even if it were not) it can also be empty. This solution seems not applicable in any of the cases, or am I wrong?

Comment: It wont throw any exception

Comment: @Ivan you can use "0"  it will select empty if values does not exists

Comment: @Ivan you can also set the the default value in catch

Comment: _Exceptions should not be used to change the flow of a program as part of ordinary execution_  From [Things to Avoid When Throwing Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/creating-and-throwing-exceptions#things-to-avoid-when-throwing-exceptions).

Comment: @Fabio i totally agree but since it was only Combo so i thought it wont make much difference

Comment: Unless you have hundreeds of such "Combos" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add "default" value to the binding source.
Suppose you have a `ShippingMethod` class which you bind to the `ComboBox`

```
public class ShippingMethod
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create a instance of `ShippingMethod` with "default" values and add it to the `BindingList<ShippingMethod>` every time you update value.
An use `Dictionary` for checking if given value exists, if not - set default

```
private Dictionary<int, ShippingMethod> _allMethods;
private ShippingMethod _defaultShippingMethod = new ShippiingMethod 
{
    Id = 0, Name = "Not selected"
}

private void SetUpShippingMethods(IEnumerable<ShippingMethod> methods)
{
    _allMethods = methods.ToDictionary(method => method.Id);
    var shippingMethods = new List<ShippingMethod> { _defaultShippingMethod };

    shippingMethods.AddRange(methods);

    _comboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
    _comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
    _comboBox.DataSource= shippingMethods;
}

private void SetSelectedShippingMethod(ShippingMethod method)
{
    If (method == null)
    {
        _comboBox.SelectedValue = _defaultMethod.Id;
        return;
    }

    if (_allMethods.ContainsKey(method.Id))
    {
        _comboBox.SelectedValue = method.Id;
    }
    else
    {
        _comboBox.SelectedValue = _defaultMethod.Id;
    }
}
```

If you use `MVVM` and have `ViewModel` where properties `Methods` and `SelectMethod` - you can use same methods in the viewmodels , but instead setting them straight to `ComboBox` you just return "handled" collection or "handled" selected value.

If you don't want using this code in your `ViewModel` you can use them in the `Binding.Format` event on the view side.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use combobox.SelectedItem in replacement? It should return the same values, and I believe it can be set to null.