# C# ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1; not showing blank, its showing first record

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have `ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;` set for a combobox in a windows form.

However when I open the form it loads in the first value from the DB rather than blank.

I have used `ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;` on other forms and it works correctly in showing a blank.

It sits inside:

```
private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    employeeIDComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Which is showing:

[image]

Working on another form with the same code:

```
private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    regComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Which works showing:

[image]

Comment: Is the DataSource of the combobox set? If the DataSource is set, chances are the underlying currency manager won't allow the -1/empty position. If the combobox is filled through its items (Items.Add/AddRange), it should work

Comment: @Me.Name yes a data source is set for the combobox

Comment: Is it an option to not set the datasource, but to fill the items with the underlying collection with `employeeIDComboBox.Items.Add`(Range)?  (otherwise temporarily setting the datasource to null and resetting it on dropdown might be an option, but using the Items would be easier)

Comment: I dont see what is different between the two, they both look at a single table, they both have the same code and same options set

Comment: To deselect the currently selected item, set the SelectedIndex to -1. You cannot set the SelectedIndex of a ComboBox item to -1 if the item is a data-bound item.

Comment: The answers may help you. [How to deleselect / blank a databound ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427172/how-to-deleselect-blank-a-databound-combobox-selectedindex-1-does-not-work)

Comment: @Sphinx You can, i have 6 others that are databound doing exactly that

Comment: @Matt The property=[FormattingEnable] of all 7 combobox are same? As API defines: If FormattingEnabled is false, SelectedIndex will not be set to -1 when SelectedValue is blank.

Comment: @Sphinx The setting `FormattingEnabled` is set to `True` for all combo boxes

Comment: Do you have some event handler in that combobox? If yes, what do you do in that handler?

Comment: @Steve there are a few textbox.visible = true in bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click if thats what you mean

Comment: I am trying to isolate the differences between this combo and the others. One step could be to remove any event handler for SelectedIndexChanged and check if something changes. Other steps is to observe if there are any difference in the properties settings.

Comment: @Steve There are no differences between the ones that are showing correctly and the one that doesn't work correctly.